# Сложный динамический Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, разметка, layout

Есть layout.xml в нем около 100 textView и порядка 20-30 картинок, картинки сам по себе маленькие максимум 50 Кб. Этот layout привязан к активити, который меняет значение textView при изменении seekView при котором происходят не особо сложные вычисления. Так вот это нормальная практика создавать layout ресурс с 2000 строчек кода в XML. Можно ли как то это все оптимизировать. Первая мысль все сделать в контейнерах, но как к ним обращаться при вычленении.

Comment: это не нормальная практика. для отображения большого количества однотипных виджетов используют виджеты с адаптерами:recyclerview, gridview и подобные.

Comment: Да я понимаю это, и с удовольствием бы сделать так, но все не однотипны в этом и вся проблема

Comment: Практика не нормальная, делайте через `RecyclerView` с кастомным адаптером. Обращение к контейнерам - через список, с которым адаптер работает + `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: как минимум, вам надо было бы пересмотреть подход в целом. Возможно как то перераспределить логику и изменить архитектуру.  Для более хорошего совета по поводу оптимизации опишите вашу задачу более детально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае, когда есть много вьюх на одном экране, которые надо отобразить и скорее всего скролить, но они не однотипны, в последнее время хорошей практикой является применение `DelegateAdapter`. Их можно написать самому не слишком сложно или взять [либу](https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates).

[Вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/341738/) общая статья на эту тему на хабре.

Делать тяжелые xml это плохая идея как и с точки зрения производительности, так и с точки зрения масштабируемости, поддерживаемости.